# sf 1.4 Access & customize embededObject() in root form

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4

I got a problem to save custom values for embededforms in root form.

I can actually edit a "manifestation" and i can add as much as i want "commande_wifi".
Everything is good saved.

I need to customize the process for every "commande_wifi" ( there is a 'puht' value depending on other values of the object() ). I have already lost a few hours only to do that.

> 1. save() is only called on the root form
>
> That’s right! Only the root form has save() called. So if there’s other logic you want to run, you will want to override the saveEmbeddedForm method and call that code before. Oversimplification ahead: when you save a form with embedded forms, it calls $this->getObject()->save(), then it calls saveEmbeddedForms, which, for each embedded form, calls $form->saveEmbeddedForms() and then calls $form->getObject()->save(). This is critical to know, as it will save you a lot of headaches later on.
> http://jmather.com/2011/01/29/6-things-to-know-about-embedded-forms-in-symfony/

I've tried to overwrite the saveembededForms() but fail at this point.

```
class manifestationForm extends BasemanifestationForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->embedRelation('commande_wifi');

  }

  public function addNewFields($number){
    $new_commandes = new BaseForm();

    for($i=0; $i <= $number; $i+=1){
      $commande = new Commande_wifi();
      $commande->setManifestation($this->getObject());
      $commande_form = new commande_wifiForm($commande);

      $new_commandes->embedForm($i,$commande_form);
    }

    $this->embedForm('new', $new_commandes);
  }

  public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null){

    $new_commandes = new BaseForm();
    foreach($taintedValues['new'] as $key => $new_commande){
      $commande = new Commande_wifi();
      $commande->setManifestation($this->getObject()); 
      $commande_form = new commande_wifiForm($commande);

      $new_commandes->embedForm($key,$commande_form);
    }

    $this->embedForm('new',$new_commandes);          

    parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
  }

  public function saveEmbeddedForm($con = null, $forms = null)
  {
      if ($con === NULL)
      {
        $con = $this->getConnection();
      }

      if ($forms === NULL)
      {
        $forms = $this->getEmbeddedForms();
      }

      foreach ($forms as $form)
      {
        if ($form instanceof sfFormObject)
        {
          $form->saveEmbeddedForms($con);
          $form->getObject()->setPuht(99);
          $form->getObject()->save($con);
        }
        else
        {
          $this->saveEmbeddedForms($con, $form->getEmbeddedForms());
        }
        //$form->getObject()->setPuht(99)->save();

      }    
  }
}
```

It's won ASAP i can access the embedForm Object().

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think you should override the `doUpdateObject()` method in the embedded form instead. Steps: 1. call the parent, 2. check if the field exists in the from and in the values, 3. update the object by the value in the values array (do not save the object here). (If the `puht` value not depends on the form you should move this into the model e.g. into `preSave` or `preInsert` and/or `preUpdate`.)

Comment: thx for your fast response! i'll check that tomorow and update the thread in the afternoon. ( puht depends of the embededform object other values, i ve just setPuht() for dev purpose, if this work, i can access other values get..() to calculate the puht )